# Django Framework: ModuleNotFoundError...'bootstrapform'

Tags: python, django, pip

I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrapform'` but I have already installed `django-bootstrap-form`.

I have read other questions here where the fix has been to install that module, but in my case this is not working. I have the same site running on my laptop and can see no difference so it is confusing.

So here is the module list:

[image: after running <code>pip3 list</code>]
Here is the error:

[image: after running <code>makemigrations</code>]

...and here is the `INSTALLED_APPS` section of `settings.py`:

[image: <code>settings.py</code>]

I can't see the problem...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `py -3` command. How does that work? Are you sure it's using the same environment as `pip3` does? Have you tried `python manage.py makemigrations` or `python3 manage.py makemigrations` instead?

Comment: from: "Note: On Windows you launch Python 3 scripts by prefixing the command with py -3, while on Linux/macOS X, the command is python3" - I'll try the command you mentioned

Comment: from this guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/development_environment

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm afraid I can't spot the problem. Hope you figure it out.

Comment: replacing "py -3" with "python" seems to have done the trick, thanks. It seems the guide I was using (I'm new to Python) is outdated - thanks for your help

Comment: The tutorial is using Django 2.0 so it's fairly recent. I don't use Windows so I can't tell why `py -3` isn't working for you or whether it's a good recommendation in general. However I can see that the [Django Girls tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/) instructs Windows users to use `python` after activating the virtual environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `py -3` is not using the `django_env` virtualenv that `pip3` is using. Once you have activated your virtualenv, you can simply use `python`.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```